# add a stored column in mySql using phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have tried the following to add a new column in an existing table "leavedata". I get an error saying delimiter is missing. My environment is MySQL using phpMyAdmin.

```sql
ALTER TABLE leavedata
  ADD empDept text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    SELECT empdata.eDept
      FROM empdata
      WHERE empdata.`empID` = leavedata.`empID`
  ) STORED;
```

If this is not the method, could you please tell me the "Expression" I need to provide when I add the column manually. Or the SQL statement for ALTER from another table.

Comment: Remember, phpMyAdmin is just a front-end, one of many for MySQL.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you get?